# Turn off Google Voice forwarding when using home Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, google-voice

I use Google Voice to forward phone calls to my Android phone. But when I am at home, I would like to save voice minutes by not having to answer phone using my voice plan. Is there a way to automatically turn off Google Voice forwarding to my cell number (only the cell number if possible) when I am on my home's Wi-Fi?

Comment: Are you home at specific predetermined times? Because on Google Voice's site, you can specify time periods you want a specific phone number to accept forwarded calls.

Comment: Negative. It might work for some days but it is not something I want to count on.